# How can I make the image I have change to another image when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I tried using JavaScript but I think It's in the wrong spot. What I have so far.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Public Vision</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="backbone" href="backbone.css">
    <link rel="alternative stylesheet" type="text/css" title="alt" href="alt.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body class="style2">
    <div id="header" class="style2"><div id="header2" class="style2">Public Vision</div></div>
    <iframe width="640" height="400" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLX9_I-EOJPdFuOjcI2zkmTck55homHEBE" 
    frameborder="2" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <input id="showHideContainer" type="image" src="on.jpg " height="3%" width="2%" alt="On" onclick="toggle();changeImage();">
     <script>
     document.getElementById('showHideContainer').onclick = function () {
divTest = document.getElementById('header');
if (divTest.style.display === "none") {
    divTest.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    divTest.style.display = "none";
};
   function changeImage() {
var image = document.getElementById('showHideContainer');
if (image.src.match("off")) {
    image.src = "on.jpg";
} else {
    image.src = "off.jpeg";
}
 };
$('body').toggleClass('style2');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I put the JavaScript to change the image on click in the wrong spot or set it up incorrectly, any help would be appreciated, or if you know of a better way to do what I want that'd be great. Thanks in advance.

Here is my CSS as well:

```
  #header { height: 15%; width: 100%; background-color: white; z-index: 2; position: fixed; right:0; top:0;


  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;
 }   

#header2{height: 15%; width: 100%; position: fixed; color:grey; opacity: 0.6; text-align: center; z-index: 4; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 2.5%; background-color:clear;}
 iframe {display:block; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 17%;}


 body{
background-color:#404040; z-index:3; transition: background-color 2s; 
 }
 body.style2{
background-color:white; z-index:3;
 }
```

Comment: There is no toggle() function maybe it is giving an error and it is unable to reach to changeImage() func

Comment: if I remove the changeImage() function the toggle() function works.

Comment: @AustinJones hey i just noticed from looking at your profile that you've accepted nearly all your answers but not for this question? Not even an upvote!!! Upvotes never go astray.. An accept would be nice though!!! thx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9jwnoxcr/

Prerequisite: jQuery

HTML:

```
<img id="imgTarget" src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#imgTarget').click(function(){
    $('#imgTarget').attr('src', 'http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg');
});
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, sorry I forgot to mention I'm using <input id="showHideContainer" type="image" src="on.png "> not a simple <img> tage

Comment: Dumb question but do I just throw it into the javascript I already have or start another script. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: nevermind it works! Thanks sooo much! on a side note, do you know how to make it so when I click again it goes back to the original image?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7ypth346/1/

HTML:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
     display:block;
     width:600px;
     height:300px;
     background: url(http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg) no-repeat;
}

a:hover {
     background: url(http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Javascript:

```
 $('a').click(function(){
     $('a').css('background', 'url(http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg) no-repeat');
 });
```

Comment: I don't want to change the background image. I want to change the image of the picture I'm using.

Comment: on the click event, just do: $('img').attr('src','newimage.jpg');

Comment: Ok so I tried this and it still didn't work :/ not sure why.

Comment: Hold on, I'll do another answer post.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two images: img1.jpg and img2.jpg
You would change the src property of the IMG, in its onclick property

```
<img src="img1.jpg" onclick="this.src='img2.jpg'"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function .click jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/f36pzdx1/2/

Example:

```js
var checkon=0;


$('.btn').click(function(){
    if(checkon == 0){
        $('.btn').removeClass('off');
        $('.btn').addClass('on');
        checkon = 1;
    }
    else{
        $('.btn').removeClass('on');
     $('.btn').addClass('off');
        checkon = 0;
    }
});
```

```css
.btn{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
     background: url('http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-4eccf133ec34afe579f9534b992ff6ed?convert_to_webp=true');
    background-size:100%;
}
.off{
    background: url('http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/wp-content/uploads/IEC5009_Standby_Symbol.svg_.png');
    background-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn"></div>
```

I hope this helps. o/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go you have to include the script inline or it won't work in the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhbeom2b/)

```html
<script>
    function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/stop.png")) {
        image.src = "http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/play.png";
    } else {
        image.src = "http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/stop.png";
    }
}
</script>
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/stop.png" width="100" height="100">
```